# How much memory needs the Kernel?

Tags: kernel

How much memory is needed so the kernel can be loaded in the memory?

Comment: Your question was not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel modules are not particularly large.  Generally speaking, a kernel module occupies only the amount of physical RAM needed for it to load.

Linux uses a "slab-based" memory allocation scheme in which pools of memory are set-aside for different-sized memory objects. The amount of physical memory allocated changes almost every second.  So how much RAM does the Kernel?  That depends.

You can use `lsmod`, which will show you information about the modules that are loaded in RAM.